# Confusion In A Problem Of Angular Momentum

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics

Question :

Suppose you are standing on the edge of a spinning platform and step off at right angles to the edge (radially outward). Now consider it the other way. You are standing on the ground next to a spinning carousel and you step onto the platform at right angles to the edge (radially inward).

Options :

(A) There is no change in rotational speed of the carousel in either situation.

(B)There is a change in rotational speed in the first situation but not the second.

(C) There is a change in rotational speed in the second situation but not the first.

(D) There is a change in rotational speed in both instances.

The given Answer Is (C).

I think it should be (D).

My Approach:

I noticed that The Torque produced by friction in either cases will pass through the centre and hence Angular Momentum can be conserved from that point.
As we can see , in either cases Moment Of Inertia Of system is changing as the man is stepping up/down.
Hence , the angular velocity should change in both cases.

Where am I going Wrong?

Comment: I agree with you. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So when you step off the plate you are still moving and so you are carrying the angular momentum with you, when you step on you get accelerated.

Similar problem to think about: if you are going along in a car and throw a rock out the side the rock is moving at the same speed as the car and hence the car doesn't speed up or slow down. If you throw the rock backwards, so that the rock was stationary, then the car would speed up